# getDownloadUrl(); is giving error (cannot resolve symbol)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

While calling

```
task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

I am getting error on getDownloadUrl() do not know why ?
showing red line on it and cannot resolve symbol

```
if (task.isSuccessful()){
         Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image is Stored Successfully to Firebase Storage... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl.toString();

         userRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
}
```

Comment: In description you have written task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

 but in code it is task.getResult().getDownloadUrl.toString();    missing parenthesis after getDownloadUrl

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the parentheses on the `getDownloadUrl` call (assuming it is a method which exists on the type returned by `getResult()`). This should work:

```
final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Comment: sir it was mistaken but i put paranthesis and it still not working